# Adding comments at content creation?

Tags: 7, nodes, comments

I'm on D7. I have a content type that I would like users to add comments to WHILE they create it. Basically the content type is a "how to" topic and the comments will be used as different steps to do whatever. Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I'd have a look at the [field_collection](https://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. It may be more suited for your purposes.

Comment: We use this method on our internal and external knowledge systems on our "how to" content types and it works very well